# Does this Dlookup have incorrect syntax?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there something with this Dlookup syntax? It's not working when I select a value in the Combo0.

```
=DLookUp("[Employee]","tb1","[Employee]= '" & [Forms]![Form1]![Combo0] & "'")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please tell us more about how it's not working.  Is there an error message?  If you go to the Immediate window, paste in `Debug.Print DLookUp("[Employee]","tb1","[Employee]= '" & [Forms]![Form1]![Combo0] & "'")` and press Enter, does it show you the correct value?  If not what exactly happens there?

Comment: When I do that it says Null

Comment: Then what does `Debug.Print [Forms]![Form1]![Combo0]` show you?

Comment: 1 which is the uniqueID number. How come it doesn't show the name?

Comment: `[Forms]![Form1]![Combo0]` is a short form for `[Forms]![Form1]![Combo0].Value`  The `Value` comes from the combo's *Bound Column*.  If it's not practical to switch the *Bound Column* to the one which contains the employee names, can you do the `DLookup` based on the `uniqueID` number?

Comment: `[forms]![form1]![combo0].column(0)` is the first column in the combo box. Often hidden. You can replace the column number to suit which you want to use